# How to remove vertical scrollbar in button of xaml wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I just made one button with Control.Template and now facing one issue.
Because Button Text doesn't appear and one vertical scroll bar appeared.
What's the problem in my case.
Here is my code.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectInputTheme" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border Background="#2F3136" BorderBrush="#EB761C" x:Name="SelectedBorder"  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="10">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2F3136" TargetName="SelectedBorder" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#808182"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="SelectedBorder" Value="#A8A8A8"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2F3136" TargetName="SelectedBorder" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#808182"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="SelectedBorder" Value="#A8A8A8"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="#1B1C1D" BorderBrush="#A8A8A8" x:Name="SelectedBorder" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="10">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FEFEFE" TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#A8A8A8" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFF" TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1B1C1D" TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#A8A8A8"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#808182" TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="logo.png" Width="145" Height="89"/>
            <TextBlock 
                FontSize="68" Text="S t r i m o" Foreground="#808182" Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox 
                Text="Username" AcceptsReturn="False" Width="543" Height="59" FontSize="30" 
                Padding ="10" Foreground="#A8A8A8" Template="{StaticResource SelectInputTheme}"/>
            <TextBox Margin="10,0,0,0"  Text="Password" Width="543" Height="59" FontSize="30" 
                     Padding ="10" Foreground="#A8A8A8" Template="{StaticResource SelectInputTheme}"/>
            <Button Width="543" Height="59" MaxHeight="59" Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate1}" >
                <TextBlock>LOG IN</TextBlock>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

And I got this button now.  

[image: No Button Text and Vertical Scrollbar in the Button]

Please let me know which one is wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait... You have Buttons in your Buttons?

Comment: Assuming you got it working. How does the user scroll your scrollviewer? Other than clicking on something which is in your button?  If you're rounding corners then you need  a plan to cope with those rounded corners. Meaning you need to allow for them using a margin on your contentpresenter. Also. Your log in text will probably be very difficult to read with the colours you've chosen.  Maybe it's a big chinese logogram though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button content template `ButtonTemplate1` you use a `ScrollViewer` as content host.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
```

Instead, you should use a `ContentPresenter`.

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
```

This is the adapted control template.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate1"
                 TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="SelectedBorder"
            Background="#1B1C1D"
            BorderBrush="#A8A8A8" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="10">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#FEFEFE"
                    TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="#A8A8A8" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#FFFFFF"
                    TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#1B1C1D"
                    TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="#A8A8A8"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#808182"
                    TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The additional `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` bindings will apply the values of the button on which the template is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put a `<ScrollViewer />` element in the template if you don't want one?

Replace it with a `ContentPresenter` and make sure to bind its `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties to the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` of the templated `Button`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border Background="#1B1C1D" BorderBrush="#A8A8A8" x:Name="SelectedBorder" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="10">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FEFEFE" TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#A8A8A8" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFF" TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1B1C1D" TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#A8A8A8"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#808182" TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```